# CollapsingToolbarLayout not showing Title

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

In my case, the toolbar disappears when I scroll through the list. I am using a CollapsingToolbarLayout and I need to set the title text. But in my case the title text is not showing, even though I've set it (See code below). What is wrong?

**Layout code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:elevation="0dp"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/app_nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**Activity code:**

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.app_activity_with_left_panel);

    mPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    mCollapsingToolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout)findViewById(R.id.collapsing);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    setTitle(getIntent().getStringExtra(TITLE));
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    if (title != null && !title.toString().isEmpty()) {
        mTitle = title.toString();
        mCollapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle(mTitle);
    }
}
```

Comment: remove that `@override` tag and try again.

Comment: @vrund purohit not works.

Comment: try this  :  ActionBar ab = getActionBar();
    ab.setTitle("My Title");

Comment: @GPPSoft Do `getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Title");`.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Remove this

```
@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    if (title != null && !title.toString().isEmpty()) {
        mTitle = title.toString();
        mCollapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle(mTitle);
    }
}
```

and add this on your `OnCreate()`.

```
    mCollapsingToolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout)findViewById(R.id.collapsing);
    mCollapsingToolbarLayout.setTitleEnabled(false);

    mToolbar.setTitle("title");
```

This disables the default title with collapsing behaviour and adds the static title to the toolbar.

Comment: @GPPSoft see my answer.

Comment: @Ironman Thx. Now it works. But not setting eny title text. Show default app name. :( mCollapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle("title"); not change title.

Comment: @Ironman Still show default app name title. I try to change title< but not changed.

Comment: @Ironman Sorry. This is works. It does not change the header when the application starts(show default appname). But if you change it when you click on button it works. Why is that?

Comment: @GPPSoft is your problem solved ? app would show the name of defualt app as it starts it take app name from manifest i.e defined in string/app_name , and you're using shared preferences to set title so first you have to make some click actions so that shared preferences get something it and then you can set title.

Comment: @Ironman Now it works! I changed to getSupportActionBar().setTitle(...); and title changed. But how set title on CollapsingToolbarLayout in my case&? Why mCollapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle() not works? Thx!

Comment: @GPPSoft this `mCollapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle() ` not work because we set  `mCollapsingToolbarLayout.setTitleEnabled(false);` to false.we can only set it when this `mCollapsingToolbarLayout.setTitleEnabled(true)`  is true.

Comment: @Ironman i set mCollapsingToolbarLayout.setTitleEnabled(true), but not works.

Comment: @GPPSoft read this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.html

Comment: @GPPSoft it is work but you have set it for `Expand` and `Collapse` both for that.

Answer (score 16):

For who searches for disabling the title just add

```
app:titleEnabled="false"
```

Then the title of the toolbar itself would appear so we will disable it with

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

or with those line in the style xml

```
<item name="android:displayOptions">showHome|useLogo</item>
<item name="displayOptions">showHome|useLogo</item>
```

Searched too much to make this search summary, wish it helps.

Comment: you solved my problem. thx. especially the "setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);"

Answer (score 4):

In my case the problem was due to setting Toolbar layout_height to "wrap_content". After setting this property to a specific value like `?attr/actionBarSize`, CollapsingToolbarLayout title become visible.

Answer (score 3):

The above answers are correct, but it took me multiple tries to get it right.  I ended up setting `app:titleEnabled="false"` for my CollapsingToolbarLayout in the xml, setting nothing for the Toolbar itself.

In the code, I set `supportActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true)`, and `supportActionBar.title = "my title"`.

---

My code:

layout.xml:

```xml
<com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_main_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:toolbarId="@id/toolbar"
    app:titleEnabled="false">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_main" />

</com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

fragment.kt:

```kotlin
val toolbar = view.findViewById<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar)
myTitle = "This is my app title"

(activity as AppCompatActivity).let { myActivity ->
    myActivity.setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    myActivity.supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true)
    myActivity.supportActionBar?.title = myTitle 

    // these are not needed:
    //collapsingToolbar.title = myTitle 
    //collapsingToolbar.isTitleEnabled = true
    //toolbar.title = myTitle 
    //myActivity.title = myTitle         
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use this :

`app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"` with your `CollapsingToolbarLayout`

Comment: remove that override method